# Nav in bootstrap when in landscape view not aligned properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `navbar` with images, which has 2 sets of `ul` tags. The first set has the logo images to the left and the second set has the social media icons to the left. When viewed on mobile I want it in such a way that logos comes in first line and social media icons under it centered. It is working perfectly on all devices but not on iPhone landscape view where the social media icons come in on the second line but are not centered.

Here is the code I use:

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 " >
        <div class="cliente">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="logos/sailCaribe_logo.jpg" alt="Saile Caribe"></li>
            <li><img src="images/atthe.jpg" alt="Sail Caribe"></li>
            <li><img src="logos/theYachtClub_logo.jpg" alt="Yacht Club"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5"><div  class="cliente1">
        <ul >
          <li><a href="#"><img src="logos/twitter_icon.jpg" alt="twitter"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="logos/youTube_icon.jpg" alt="youtube"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="logos/facebook_icon.jpg" alt="facebook"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="log/instagram_icon.jpg"alt="instagram"></a></l1>  
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @nolawipetros It's a css Framework. OP doesn't need to include his CSS for these kinds of questions unless they are using custom classes.Now then, notice on your last `<li>` tag, your closing tag says `</l1>`... That might cause some issues.

Comment: @TimLewis i asked because he has ` <div class="cliente">` twice?

Comment: @nolawipetros Eh I suppose, but you made it sound like you expected him to post **all** his css. Either way, no reply in close to an hour, doubtful to expect one I guess.

Comment: this is class cliente      .cliente {
 margin-top:10px;
float:left;}

Comment: @TimLewis  rest everything  regular bootstrap.  class  cliente .cliente { margin-top:10px; float:left;}

Comment: have you tried swapping the outermost `.container-fluid` and `.nav`?

Comment: @nozzleman i tried it … still not working.. its working on most of the screen resolutions but my client is particular about iPhone.. its working on vertical  but not on landscape.. where it is positioned on line two but towards the right